# how to optimize the insert statement to achive utmost performance

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

Iam using `JDBC"` and i wrote the below "insertRecord" method, and it suppose to be called numerous times and insert records into data base table. when i run the code for each 500 records "which the size of the batch"
it takes 20 seconds and it is very slow as that code should be run 30 times on different xml files to segregate them and insert some data into the data base table.

is there any advice how to optimize the code to achive utmost performance?

**CreateTable methods**

```
public void CreateTable(String tableName) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    if (this.isTableExists(tableName)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "CreateTable", "table: ["+tableName+"] already exists.");

        this.connInsert  = this.getConnection();
        this.connInsert.setAutoCommit(true);
        this.psInsert = this.connInsert.prepareStatement("insert into "+this.TABLE_NAME+" ("+this.NODE_ID_COL+", "+this.LAT_COL+", "+this.LNG_COL+", "+this.XML_PATH_COL+") values (?, ?, ?, ?)");

    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "CreateTable", "table: ["+tableName+"] does not exist, will be created");
        Connection conn = this.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(this.sqlTable);

        stmt.close();
        conn.close();

        this.connInsert  = this.getConnection();
        this.connInsert.setAutoCommit(true);
        this.psInsert = this.connInsert.prepareStatement("insert into "+this.TABLE_NAME+" ("+this.NODE_ID_COL+", "+this.LAT_COL+", "+this.LNG_COL+", "+this.XML_PATH_COL+") values (?, ?, ?, ?)");

    }
}
```

**insertRecord methods**

```
public void insertRecord(Record rec) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    if (this.isTableExists(this.TABLE_NAME)) {

        this.psInsert.setString(1, rec.getNodeID());
        this.psInsert.setString(2, rec.getLat());
        this.psInsert.setString(3, rec.getLng());
        this.psInsert.setString(4, rec.getPath());

        this.psInsert.addBatch();

        if (++this.batchCnt == SysConsts.BATCH_SIZE) {
            this.psInsert.executeBatch();
            this.batchCnt = 0;

            Log.d(TAG, "insertRecord", SysConsts.BATCH_SIZE+" records inserted.");
        }

    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "insertRecord", "table: ["+this.TABLE_NAME+"] does not exist");
    }

}
```

**fluch methods, to flush the remaining records in the batch**

```
//this method should be called in the end of the code to flush the remaining records in the batch

public void flush() throws SQLException {
    this.psInsert.executeBatch();

    this.psInsert.close();
    this.connInsert.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "insertRecord", "the rest of the records flushed into data base table.");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the typical answers:

- use the same store procedure (or some prepare statement as you did)
- **wrap all inserts in one transaction** (very important as it'll reduce the amount of io writes)
- change for connection types (like journal in sqlite)
- use blobs (very rare)

Comment: i think, in my code posted, i achieved the 2nd and the last points u mentioned, but concerning the 1st and 3rd points u mentioned, i would appreciate it if u provided an examples

Comment: I think because of `this.connInsert.setAutoCommit(true);` in particular, you are not using a single transaction. Try to set it to `false` instead

Comment: i am working on JDB and sqlite, and there is no stored procedures in sqlite. any recommendations? MongoDB?

Comment: @rmaik, I think the `prepareStatement` will be on par with StoredProcedure anyway, except for its creation (once)

Answer (score -1):

Use [stored procedures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure). They are much faster than normal SQL execution.

> A procedure's query plan is typically cached, allowing you to reuse it
> again and again without needing to re-prepare it.
>
> Since stored procedures are Parsed, Compiled at once, and the
> executable is cached in the Database. Therefore if same query is
> repeated multiple times then Database directly executes the executable
> and hence Time is saved in Parse,Compile etc. This is good if query is
> used frequently. If query is not used frequently, then it might not be
> good, because storing cached executable takes space, why to put Load
> on Database unnecessarily.

Comment: can u please provide an example how to convert the insert method posted above to Stored Procedure?